# Show that S is sigma-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma-$algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and suppose that $B\in \mathcal{A}.$ Show that $\mathcal{S}=\left\{A\cap B: A\in \mathcal{A}\right\}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra of subsets of $B$.

Hello, can you help me this problem please?  :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $B= \Omega \cap B$, which means $B \in \mathcal{S}$.

2) Let $C \in \mathcal{S}$, then $C=A\cap B$ for some $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Note that

$B \setminus C = B \cap (A \cap B)^c = B \cap (A^c \cup B^c) = (A^c \cap B) \cup (B^c \cap B) = A^c \cap B$,

(where $X^c = \Omega \setminus X$, for every $X\subseteq \Omega$). Since $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$, thus $B \setminus C \in \mathcal{S}$.

3) Let $(B_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$. Then for every $n \geq 1$, $B_n = A_n \cap B$ for some $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$. Note that

$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n \cap B) = \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) \cap B.$

Since $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathcal{A}$, then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \in \mathcal{S}$.